# Entity Framework Performance - How do I get this to work fast?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have an object that has a list of child objects, basically its an institution that has multiple departments.  Departments can be disabled or enabled based on a boolean property on the department.  I would like to trigger a property of the institution to false when there are 1 or more departments that are disabled.  I have the following code in my partial institution class:

```
public bool AllSet
{
    get
    {
        return !(Departments.Where(i => i.Active == false && i.IsDeleted == false).Count() > 0);
    }
}
```

This works, but when I have it enabled the performance of my page that shows the list of institutions slows to a crawl and memory usage spikes, apparently I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, does anyone have any alternative ways to do this?

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```
    var institutions = from x in ent.Institutions let hasDepartments = 
!x.Departments.Any(d => d.Active == false && d.IsDeleted == false) select new { 
                FullTitle = x.Title + " - " + x.Address.Line1 + ", " + x.Address.City + ", " + x.Address.State, Department = x, AllSet = hasDepartments, Guid = x.Guid
            };
            instList.DataSource = institutions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find marginal performance benefit by using the following query. However the main issue is that Linq IS unperformant. By definition it is generating a SQL query at run time and in order to do so a large amount of meta-data is generated. You will find that .net 4.5 has lower overheads than .net 4 in this regards.

If there seems to be a large cost for the first query, it could also be due to the view creation process. You can take a look at pre-compiled views. But ultimately if you need speed, look elsewhere. Perhaps even inline SQL.

```
public bool AllSet
{
    get
    {
        return !(Departments.Any(i => i.Active == false && i.IsDeleted == false));
    }
}
```

Edit: I just realised your REAL issue. It looks like `AllSet` is a method on the class Institution and you are calling it on a tight loop. I assume its "working" because of Lazy loading.

This is hugely bad as each loop you are going to be making a database call, which is going to be IO/latency bound and hence extremely slow. Also instead of just loading a `bool` from the database, each and every associated `Department` is loaded on demand and then the `.Count()` is run locally on .net (hence the large memory footprint).

Try to prefetch each institution along with if they have active departments.

```
var institutions = from x in context.Institutions
                   where {blah}
                   let hasDepartments = x.Departments.Any(d => d.Active == false 
                                   && i.IsDeleted == false)
                   select new { Department = x, AllSet = hasDepartments};
foreach(var institution in institutions)
{
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Overall the real WTF is that you are relying on EF Lazy Loading.

Comment: Alternatively you could EAGER load Departments, but that would mean loading all the Deparments and not just some bool...

Comment: I like the idea of working it all into the query, I will try this tomorrow and post back

Comment: I have added my variation of your answer to my original question, thanks for your help, I will be using this approach to populate larger lists from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
public bool AllSet
{
    get
    {
        return !(Departments.Count(i => i.Active == false && i.IsDeleted == false) > 0);
    }
}
```

There are tips to improve your EF performance, check this [link](http://rahulgbhatia.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/tips-to-improve-entity-framework-performance/). (For those who use EF, this is worth to read)

Comment: This approach uses marginally less memory (might not be any different) and is still quite slow..very weird.