# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Linq.iQueryable<int>'

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So I'm a bit stuck! Doing a programming assignment for college and I hit a wall.

The question we were given in one of our parts is as follows:

"2. 
Allow the user to find the customers that have placed an order in a particular year. Provide a 
combo box which lists all the unique (distinct) years in orders table from which the user can 
make a selection."

I'm having an issue with converting the "Year" so I can compare it with the OrderID and display all the orders that are in the database, in a listbox.

If anyone could give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
private void dateDDL_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selection;
    selection = dateDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();

    var year = from y in northwind.Orders
               where Convert.ToString(y.OrderDate).Contains(selection)
               select y.OrderID;

    var order = from o in northwind.Order_Details
                where o.OrderID == year
                select new { o.OrderID, 
                             o.ProductID, 
                             o.UnitPrice, 
                             o.Quantity, 
                             o.Discount };

    lbxOrderdate.ItemsSource = order;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the result of a query to an integer.. you need to get the value from the query with something like `First()` or `Single()` and then compare

Comment: The `var` keyword trap :-) it is not always suitable for code readability. Maybe you would have seen the problem if you had written `IQueryable<int> year`, so you see that is not an `int`.

Comment: @polkduran: better would be to name the variables appropriately.

Comment: +1 @siride , yes you are right

Comment: Personally I would cast `dateDDL.SelectedItem` to `int`. Then you don't need to do the Convert.ToString(), which might generate suboptimal SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `year` query is returning a list of all the `OrderID` values that match your `where` clause.  You can't compare that list to the single `o.OrderID` in the `order` query; if you want to find all the orders that are in one of the years returned by the `years` query, use something like

```
where year.Contains(o.OrderID)
```

(untested, but should lead you down the right route)

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Still a noob programming as you can see but at least it'll get done what needs to be done ! Thank you sir.

Comment: No worries - you're welcome. You may find the code more intuitive to read if you rename the `year` query to something more accurately descriptive, like `orderIDList`

Answer (score 4):

```
var year = (from y in northwind.Orders
                   where Convert.ToString(y.OrderDate).Contains(selection)
                   select y.OrderID).Single();

var order = from o in northwind.Order_Details
                    where o.OrderID == year
                    select new { 
                                  o.OrderID, 
                                  o.ProductID, 
                                  o.UnitPrice, 
                                  o.Quantity, 
                                  o.Discount 
                                };
```

LINQ query also returns `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>` and, if you want to take single value, you should you `Single()`/`First()` extension.

If you not sure, that query result contains objects, you should you `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` (`SingleOrDefault()` throws an exception when collection contains mere then one element), which returns `default(T)` in case when there is no elements in result. Be aware of this.

Comment: This would generate 2 Database calls. Suboptimal.

Comment: @Aron: yes, but this question not about LINQ query mappings

Comment: My point is simple. If you inlined the query or avoided using the Single call (by using contains as some other people have noted) you would have a query that takes a single database call. Not understanding how the abstraction layer works will lead to problems such as this one - [EF slow performance due to lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073150/entity-framework-performance-how-do-i-get-this-to-work-fast/16073349?noredirect=1#comment22960586_16073349).

Answer (score 1):

Type is very important, the world of (nothing but) strings is not safe.

```
string selection = dateDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
int year = Int32.Parse(selection);

var orders =
  from order in northwind.Orders
  where order.OrderDate.Year == year
  select order;
```

---

> "2. Allow the user to find the customers that have placed an order in a particular year. Provide a combo box which lists all the unique (distinct) years in orders table from which the user can make a selection."

Hmm, shouldn't the query actually be about customers?

Comment: You're right. Good spot :O. I really need to learn how to read the question better >.>